# Making sure global logger object lives longer than other global objects

Tags: c++, singleton, global-variables, shared-ptr

I have an application with some singleton objects. They want to write log messages at construction and destruction, which happens at the initialization of global variables. Now the logging provider is also a singleton object like this:

```
// loggingProvider.h
class LoggingProvider {
    static boost::shared_ptr<LoggingProvider> instance;
public:
    static boost::shared_ptr<LoggingProvider> getInstance();
    /* ... */
};

// loggingProvider.cpp
boost::shared_ptr<LoggingProvider> LoggingProvider::instance;

boost::shared_ptr<LoggingProvider> getInstance() {
    if (!instance) {
        instance.reset(new LoggingProvider());
    }
    return instance;
}
```

The logger interface looks like this:

```
// logger.h
class Logger {
    const boost::shared_ptr<LoggingProvider> provider;
    const std::string prefix;
public:
    Logger(const std::string prefix);
    /* ... */
}

// logger.cpp
Logger::Logger(const std::string& prefix) :
        provider(LoggingProvider::getInstance()), prefix(prefix) {}
```

The idea is to be able to declare loggers as global variables in multiple cpp files and be sure that the logging provider is destroyed *after* all loggers are destroyed, because it is managed by `boost::shared_ptr`. If I declare a logger like this at the top of a file, it is guaranteed to be destructed after any singleton object in the same file:

```
// somewhere.cpp
static Logger logger("Somewhere");
```

Sadly, this code doesn't work. When I debug it, the instance of `LoggingProvider` is created multiple times. I believe this is the case because the `instance` field is actually initialized after some of the logger declarations. Now I know there is no way no control the initialization of global variables across files, so is there another way to get this to work?

Comment: A good example of why Singleton is an *anti-pattern*. You may consider using a macro instead of the singleton to implement the Logger::Logger

Comment: @YZ.learner You mean a good example of why you need a singleton, rather than using something else.

Comment: @JamesKanze I mean, IMHO, one should try not to use any singleton if possible

Comment: @YZ.learner Except, of course, where a singleton is appropriate, or in this case, necessary.  (Of course, the name may be misleading here.  What we're trying to achieve is managing order of initialization; the restriction to just a single instance of the class is secondary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the classical singleton idiom.  You don't want
`shared_ptr` here, because you don't want to destruct the
object, ever.  Basically, something like:

```
class LoggingProvider
{
    static LoggingProvider* our_instance;
public:
    static LoggingProvider& instance();
    //  ...
};

LoggingProvider* LoggingProvider::our_instance
        = &LoggingProvider::instance();

LoggingProvider&
LoggingProvider::instance()
{
    if ( our_instance == NULL ) {
        our_instance = new LoggingProvider;
    }
    return *our_instance;
}
```

The important things here are 1) the pointer has no non-trivial
constructor, and 2) the instance is never destructed.

One thing: since any file you're outputting to will never be
closed, make sure you flush all output.  (I usually do this by
using short lived, temporary instances of the actual logger,
which acquire the target streambuf from the `LoggerProvider`,
and flush it in their destructor.)

Comment: But this logging provider might be destroyed when the application exits before some other singleton object is destroyed. If the destructor of that object wants to log something, the provider will already be gone and so the logger will probably segfault.

Comment: I think there still could be multiple LoggingProvider instances in a multithread program. Thread A check our_instance == NULL, thread B check our_instance == null, then they both call the constructor

Comment: I don't think multithreading is a problem here. Initialization of global variables happens before multiple threads are created. Well, you could theoretically spawn threads with global variables (who would want that?), but that's not the case here. Anyway, it's not a problem to protect the getter with a mutex.

Comment: @flyx The constructor of LoggingProvider was not called UNTIL the getter `LoggingProvider::instance()` was first called. So the initialization time did nothing to protect the mutli-instance problem.

Comment: @flyx The `LoggingProvider` will not be destructed.  Ever.

Comment: @YZ.learner If you start threads from the constructors of static objects, then there may be a problem.  But that's likely to lead to a lot of other problems as well.  The whole point of the somewhat unusual initialization of `our_logger`, however, is to ensure that there is at least one call to `LoggingProvider::instance()` before entering `main`.  So that as long as no threads are started before entering main, it is thread safe.  (There are, of course, other ways of making it thread safe as well, but they are more complicated.)

Comment: @YZ.learner Since `LoggerProvider::instance()` is used in the initialization expression of a static variable, it will be called before `main` is entered.

Comment: One final remark concerning threading: in a multithreaded environment, using the returned instance of `LoggerProvider` will require a lock.  If the solution above isn't adequate (because there are threads started in static constructors), then acquire the lock before the `if` in `instance`, and return a `std::shared_ptr` with a deletor object which frees the lock.

Comment: @James Kanze: Okay, got it now, it's living on the heap and therefore won't be destructed. This seems to work. Thanks!